# how to get Grid layout with variable column width according to the text width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am using grid layout in order to display a set of data, I am not able make column width auto adjustable,I have tried using `mGridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH)` `mGridView.setColumnWidth(textView.getWidth())` `android:stretchMode="columnWidth"` in xml file but nothing is working.This is my xml file

grid_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="6"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
     ></GridView>
```

this is may main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:textSize="6sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is where I have tried setting column width in adapter

```
public String[] mText =new String[] {
            "No", "Item Name","Quantity", "Price","Units","Amount",
            "1","Dhara Sunflower Oil","1 ltr","₹ 110","2","₹ 220",
            "2","MDH Sambhar Masala","100 gms","₹ 65","1","₹ 65",
            "3","India Gate Basmati Rice","1 kg","₹ 110","1","₹ 165"

    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mText.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mText[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        if(convertView==null){
            gridView = new View(mContext);
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
            mGridView = (GridView) parent.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
            textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(mText[position]);

            gridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    gridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    gridView.getWidth(); //height is ready
                    mGridView.setColumnWidth(textView.getWidth());
                    Log.i("TAG","TAG"+(textView.getWidth()));
                }
            });

        }else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }
        return gridView;

    }
```

It looks like this when I run it on emulator, I don't want that space between the first and second column,I mean it should be like wrap content

[image]

Comment: use StaticLayout for measure text width